# Protractor testcase failing to upload a file

Tags: protractor

I have importOBJ.JS Which is my object file and importObjSpec.js my spec file.When I use this below testcase scenario to upload a file. I am getting error element not interactable , what i am missing , I couldn't figure out.

importObj.js

```
 var importBtnId = 'import-bulk-upload';   
     this.uploadBulkImportFile = function (filePath) {
          var path = require('path');
          var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, filePath);
          element(by.id(fileInputId)).sendKeys(absolutePath);
        };
```

importObjSpec.js

```
var SImport = require('../../../../importObj.js');
    it('should attempt to upload a file with various few errors', function () {
           SImport.uploadBulkImportFile
    ('ImportInvalid.xlsx');            
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
const path = require('path');
    const fileToUpload = '../image/dummy.txt'; // image folder is present in app folder of angular project
    const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
    const fileElem = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));
    fileElem.sendKeys(absolutePath);
```